# Selenium webdriver click in more than one button at same page

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use selenium webdriver in python to click in all the thanks button on a page, but the problem is that my script is only clicking on the first button.

Below is the part of code that I´m using:

```
counter = 0
while counter < 10:
    wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@href,"post_thanks.php?do=")]').click()
    print ("click")
    counter += 1
    time.sleep(2)
wd.close()
```

The script is working, it's connecting to the website, loading the target page, but only clicks at the first thanks button.

What can be made to get all the buttons clicked?

Comment: are you sure every thanks button can be found with this xpath? If you can give the link of the site, we can find the solution more easily. It is not clear what the problem is in the question you asked, because we don't  have the html code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
wd.find_element_by_xpath('(//*[contains(@href,"post_thanks.php?do=")])[1]').click()
time.sleep(2)
wd.find_element_by_xpath('(//*[contains(@href,"post_thanks.php?do=")])[2]').click()
```

I do not know why you have the for loop, but as you can see with those xpath we identify the 2 different buttons

Without sharing the html this is the best approach I can think.

Answer (score 0):

```
thanks = wd.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@href,"post_thanks.php?do=")]')
for ta in thanks:
     ta.click()
     time.sleep()
```